# how to use a logical vector in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

3 doctors diagnose a patient

question 1 : how to filter the patient which all 3 doctors diagnose with disease B (no matter B.1, B.2 or B.3)

question 2: how to filter the patient which any of 3 doctors diagnose with disease A.

```
set.seed(20200107)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5,each =3),
                 disease = sample(c('A','B'), 15, replace = T))
df$disease <-  as.character(df$disease)
df[1,2] <- 'A'
df[4,2] <- 'B.1'
df[5,2] <- 'B.2'
df[6,2] <- 'B.3'·
df
```

I got a method but I don't know how to write the code. I think in the code `any()` or `all()` function shoule be used.

First, I want to group patients by id.

Second, check if all the disease is A or B in each group.

The code like this

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter_all(all_vars(disease == B))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all` assuming every patient is checked by 3 doctors only.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(disease_B = all(grepl('B', disease)))

#     id disease_B
#  <int> <lgl>    
#1     1 FALSE    
#2     2 TRUE     
#3     3 FALSE    
#4     4 FALSE    
#5     5 FALSE
```

If you want to subset the rows of the patient, we can use `filter`

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(all(grepl('B', disease)))
```

---

For question 2: similarly, we can use `any`

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(disease_B = any(grepl('A', disease)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), disease = c("A", "A", "A", "B.1", "B.2", 
"B.3", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think your output of the first command is wrong, the command works but you should get 2 and 4 TRUE.

Comment: @dc37 For 4 I have values "B", "A", "A". Do you have different values ?

Comment: Yes, I have only B on id 4, but I guess it is because of the use of `sample` in the definition of the dataframe. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

For the question 1, you can replace B.1 B.2 ... by B, then count the number of different "Disease" per patients and filter to keep only those equal to 3 and B:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Disease = gsub(".[0-9]+","",disease)) %>% 
  count(Disease) %>% 
  filter(n == 3 & Disease == "B")

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id Disease     n
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1     2 B           3
2     4 B           3
```

For the question 2, similarly, you can replace B.1 ... by B, then filter all rows with Disease is A, then count the number of rows per patients and your output is the patient id and the number of doctors that diagnose the disease A:

```r
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Disease = gsub(".[0-9]+","",disease))%>% 
  filter(Disease == "A") %>%  
  count(id)


# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id     n
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     3     3
3     5     2
```